# Como copiar um arquivo dentro do jar para uma pasta fora dele?

Tags: java

Eu coloquei imagens dentro de um pacote no projeto. Preciso em tempo de execução  exibir essa imagem em um programa externo (no caso notify-send do linux), esse programa precisa do caminho exato da imagem, por isso tive a idéia de copiar a imagem para dentro da pasta temporária do sistema,  ai consigo um caminho absoluto e o programa externo consegue acessar a imagem.

A idéia deu certo a principio ao executar o programa pelo Netbeans ele funciona como desejado, mas ao criar o arquivo .jar e fazer o mesmo teste o sistema "capota".

O código é esse

```
public class Main {

    public File getImagem(String fileName) throws URISyntaxException {
        String arquivo = "/pacote/imagem/" + fileName;
        //o erro acontece nessa linha abaixo, ao chamar o método toURI
        return new File(getClass().getResource(arquivo).toURI());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        String fileName = "13.jpeg";
        //caminho da imagem dentro da pasta tmp do sistema
        String imagem = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" + fileName;

        //file do arquivo que será copiado para a pasta tmp do sistema
        File tmp = new File(imagem);

        //File da imagem dentro do jar
        File src = new Main().getImagem(fileName);

        //copia arquivo de dentro do jar para a pasta temporaria
        copyFile(src, tmp);

        //exibe notificação mostrando a imagem que está dentro da pasta tmp do sistema
        exibirNotificacao(imagem, "titulo", "conteudo");
    }
    public static copyFile(File src, File destino){
         //...
    }    

    public static void exibirNotificacao(String url_imagem, String titulo, String conteudo) throws IOException {
         //...
    }
}
```

A mensagem da exceção que acontece ao executar o jar é essa

```
$ ./dist/Notify.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
    at pacote.Main.getImagem(Main.java:30)
    at pacote.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

---

**Solução**

```
public InputStream getImagem(String fileName) throws URISyntaxException {
        String arquivo = "/pacote/imagem/" + fileName;
        return getClass().getResourceAsStream(arquivo);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        String fileName = "13.jpeg";
        //caminho da imagem dentro da pasta tmp do sistema
        String destino_imagem = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" + fileName;


        InputStream inputImagem = new Main().getImagem(fileName);
        OutputStream outputImagem = new FileOutputStream(destino_imagem);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputImagem.available()];
        inputImagem.read(buffer);
        outputImagem.write(buffer);

        if(inputImagem != null)
            inputImagem.close();
        if(outputImagem!=null)
            outputImagem.close();


        //exibe notificação mostrando a imagem que está dentro da pasta tmp do sistema
        exibirNotificacao(destino_imagem, "titulo", "conteudo");
    }
```

Faltou eu tratar as exceções mas ai fica por conta de cada um, foi isso. Obrigado ao @bruno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No teu método getImagem deverias usar: `getResourceAsStream()`

```
InputStream input =  getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pacote/imagem/" + fileName);
```

Quando o recurso (imagem, ficheiro de texto, ..) está "compactado/agrupado" como um jar ou qualquer outro tipo de pacote deves usar o `getResourceAsStream`.

Isto porque o jar é um tipo de ficheiro, assim como o zip, que agrupa vários ficheiros juntos, mas para o sistema operativo é como se tratasse de um único ficheiro. Para aceder a uma parte em específico necessitas de processar o ficheiro como uma stream.

[Link para a documentação do método](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Vlw funcionou com o getResourceAsStream, só um erro na sua resposta a classe inputStream não pode ser instanciada, por que não tem construtor, vou colocar na descrição da pergunta como ficou. Obrigado.

Comment: o certo é assim `InputStream input =  getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pacote/imagem/" + fileName);`

Comment: Obrigado. Nesta maquina estou sem java pelo que foi um bocado a olho! Ainda bem que funcionou!